# spark streaming DStream map vs foreachRDD, which is more efficient for transformation

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, dstream

Just for transformation, map and foreachRDD can achieve the same goal, but which one is more efficient? And why?

for example,for a DStream[Int]:

```
val newDs1=Ds.map(x=> x+1)
val newDs2=Ds.foreachRDD (rdd=>rdd.map(x=> x+1))
```

I know foreachRDD will operate on the RDD directly, but map seams to transform DStream to RDD first(not sure), thus foreachRDD seams more efficient than map. However, map is a Transformations Operation while foreachRDD  is a Output Operations. Thus, map should be more efficient than foreachRDD while doing transformation.  Anybody knows which one is right and why? Thanks for any reply.

Add one more comparison:

```
val newDS3=Ds.transform (rdd=>rdd.map(x=> x+1))
```

which is more efficient for transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could answer this question yourself if you checked the types. `foreachRDD` is `Unit` so what you have is:

```
 val newDs2: Unit = Ds.foreachRDD (rdd=>rdd.map(x=> x+1))
```

You not only don't have `DStream[_]`, but internal `map` is never executed (it is lazy).

Following two:

```
Ds.map(x=> x+1)
Ds.transform (rdd=>rdd.map(x=> x+1))
```

are identical in terms of execution, so it doesn't make sense to use the latter one, which is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your answer!